# Book about an alien symbiote that is deadly to all, but links mankind together

Tags: story-identification

Alien lifeform (something like the blob) deadly to all races ,so dangerous that it is blockaded on a planet. Somehow a ship lands and what is left of the alien escapes to Earth and crashes in the ocean, I think. Aliens send out a ship to try and find it so they can trap it again. Alien comes in contact with a human, turns out it had just been looking for a partner/host one compatible with it. The race of man is and it starts to spread and mankind improves as it links mankind together.

Comment: Interesting. Can you remember anything else? Do people voluntarily "link" or are they taken over? Do the aliens looking for the blob-like alien come to Earth?

Comment: I think the first people are taken over, well ambushed at any rate. The aliens looking for it do find Earth , as far as I can remember they start observing and trying to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Does the story involve the internet and a bunch of telephone wires? (No joke)

Comment: Sorry no this was pre-internet , hard to imagine as it is now :)

Comment: I am looking for it too. The human runs into a cave and something falls from the caves ceiling and incapacitated him. When he wakes the thing is dead on the ground and there is a new voice in his head. It controls him as he sleeps and suddenly he knows new skills and languages. I thought it was called The Pard but can't find that either.

Comment: Phillip is looking for 'Pard' by F. Paul Wilson, incorporated into his novel 'Healer', which is not what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit like Isaac Asimov's [*Green Patches*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Patches).  But that was a short story and the details don't quite match.

The planet's creatures have green patches instead of eyes, and they are all linked to one organism.  They feel badly for the humans who are all separate and want to save them.  At one point a very small organism hides on a human spaceship, looking like a piece of wire, and plans to get to earth and "fix" humankind (who sees this as a threat.  They don't want to give up their individuality).

The part that doesn't fit is that he doesn't succeed in "improving" mankind and linking them together.

Could this be it?

Comment: Sounds like a different story to me. If anybody wants to read "Green Patches", it was published under the title "Misbegotten Missionary" in the November 1950 *Galaxy*, which is available [here](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v01n02_1950-11#page/n35/mode/2up).

Comment: It doesn't sound quite the same.  I mentioned it anyway, as sometimes what we remember is not exactly what we really read, and I thought maybe it would be helpful.  It sounds like a different story with a similar theme, but I'll let the OP decide for himself....

Comment: It also sounds a little bit (but only a little bit) like Theodore Sturgeon's [To Marry Medusa](http://www.openroadmedia.com/ebook/to-marry-medusa/): "An insatiable alien hive mind, the Medusa has already consumed the life forms of a billion planets. Now, it hungers for the dominant species of Earth. But to do so, it must somehow unite the planet’s intelligent creatures into a single shared consciousness ...".